# Jquery: how to create double .not() statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, attributes

I have 3 layers of nested menus in `<ul>`s, eg:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="somewhere.html">enu Item</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="somewhere.html">Menu Item 2</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="somewhere.html">Menu Item 3</a></li>
             </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>   
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to use Jquery to replace the href attribute of the first level of `ul`s with #, but keep the href attributes on the 2nd and 3rd a tags.

Ive created this script which works for 2nd level `ul`s but not the third level.

```
$("#menu ul li a").not("#ctamenu ul li ul a").attr("href", "#");
```

I have tried this:

```
$("#menu ul li a").not("#menu ul li ul a").not("#menu ul li ul li a").attr("href", "#")
```

But this doesnt work - the 3rd layer still has `href='#'`

Is there a way to do a "double not" statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The third level is nested in yet another `ul` that you are missing, but it would be easier to use the child selector:

```
#menu > ul > li > a
```

Comment: Sorry, I may be missing something but this gives me the same results when I try it. Are you able to extrapolate a little more?

Comment: It seems to work, but perhaps you are using it differently: http://jsfiddle.net/LBb6B/1/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your situation, you might find it helpful to create add `class="first-level"` on the first level anchor tags.  Then you could use `$('.first-level')`, which is more maintainable as the logic for your menu becomes more level dependent.